# How can I disprove that?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Prove that 5=-5
$$
\sqrt{(-5)^2} = \sqrt{25} = 5 = \sqrt{(-5)^2} = \sqrt{(-5)\cdot(-5)} = \sqrt{(-5)} \cdot \sqrt{(-5)} = (i \sqrt{5})\cdot(i\sqrt{5}) = -5\,.
$$

Comment: The function $ \ y \ = \  \sqrt{x^2} \ $ is equivalent to the absolute-value function $ \ y \ = \ | x | \ $ , which is _not_ a one-to-one function, that is, two different values of  $ \ x \ $ _can_ be assigned to the same value $ \ y \ $ from the function.    It does _not_ follow for functions that are _not_ one-to-one that $ \ f(x) \ = \ f(y) \ $ implies _only_ that  $ \ x \ = \ y \ $.

Comment: the basic point here is that $x=1 \to x^2=1$ is true, $x^2=1 \to x=1$ is false

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) =\sqrt{x}$ is the principle square root function, since 25 has two square roots the function is defined to only give the positive one otherwise it would be a relation not a function and it would be ambiguous.

The issue is this step:

$ \sqrt{(-5)(-5})= \sqrt{-5}\sqrt{-5}$

You tried to use this identity:

$\sqrt{ab}= \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$

But the rule only applies when $a,b\geq 0$